# Opening Inkscape SVG in Illustrator, not looking right

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, svg

I'm new to graphics, and had to make a small poster for a competition. I created it in Inkscape, but found out they need a .ai file. I tried opening the SVG in Illustrator, and it just does not look the same. I don't know how I can fix this!

Here's what it looks like in Inkscape:

[image]

And in Illustrator:

[image]

I know nothing about Illustrator, so I don't know if there is a simple fix for this.

For reference, here is the [file](http://www.speedyshare.com/jD3UM/cs-base.svg) as well in SVG format.

Thanks, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Inkscape has several SVG formats (inkscape, optimized, plain, compressed...). Perhaps try saving with a different SVG format (my guess would be plain) or even a format like EPS or PDF, both of which Illustrator might have better luck importing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get all those errors opening the svg file as well?

There are simply some objects which are not understood. Turn off visibility (as I've done) or delete the object layers I've highlighted in the image.

[image]

To view this image larger, right-click (Windows) or Control-click (Mac) the image and choose Open Image in new Tab/Window...

The objects appear to have something to do with the largest hang glider, but I can't figure out what they are actually suppose to create. They simply make a brown streak, then eventually cover everything.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to turn off visibility on those, but it's not working. It looks like you got it working great though. Would you mind posting a link for me to download that file? Heck, I even deleted the hang gliders, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I almost have it! Yay! The only problem now is that it seems the shadows are not being transferred correctly. Like the ones under the solar panels or the bikers. And the bikers are very heavily outlined too for some reason. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: It will depend upon many factors - how the SVG was constructed, what version of Illustrator you are using, etc. It really is a matter of deleting and possibly recreating some items in Illustrator if they don't appear correct when you open the svg file. (Note: Shadows are fine when I open the svg in AI16 [CS6])

Answer (score 2):

Try exporting it from Inkscape as a format that is likely to be well understood by Illustrator.

I would probably first try PDF.  But other relatively common exchange formats between them may include EPS and (if you're on Windows and you're desperate) WMF.